# Java Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler() not working with JUNIT?

Tags: java, junit

In the example code below, if the testMethod() is run via main() it works as expected but if it is run via JUNIT then MyUncaughtExceptionHandler does not get called.

Is there some explanation for this?

```
package nz.co.test;

import java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ThreadDemo {

  private void testMethod() {
    Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyUncaughtExceptionHandler());

    Object b = null;
    // Cause a NPE
    b.hashCode();
  }

  @Test
  public void testJunit() {
    // Run via JUnit and MyUncaughtExceptionHandler doesn't catch the Exception
    testMethod(); 
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Run via main() works as expected
    new ThreadDemo().testMethod();
  }

  static class MyUncaughtExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
      System.out.println("I caught the exception");
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: What's a weird way to cause NPE, why not just `throw new NullPointerException()`?

Comment: throw new NullPointerException() would make the bytecode in testMethod() a little different. The real code I was looking to test uses bytecode enhancement and it makes a difference in that case. If I got this to work as expected in junit I'd then enhance the testMethod().

Comment: give more details, I think we could find a better approach. Maybe you need spawn a new thread, classloader or even JVM instance in the test, but it will be integration test, not a unit test.

Comment: Imagine the code `try{Object b = null;b.hashCode();} catch(Throwable t){}`. This code will never call the `uncaughtException`. JUnit does exactly the same. And it is completely unrelated to any bytecode.

Comment: Thanks @kan.  Yes that is really the answer. It is pretty down to my misunderstanding of UncaughtExceptionHandler and obviously JUNIT wraps all the tests with try catch. Thanks for your effort to explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because all exception that are thrown in a test are caught and processed by JUnit, so UncaughtExceptionHandler doesnt get any uncaught exceptions. It is done in org.junit.runners.ParentRunners

```
...
    protected final void runLeaf(Statement statement, Description description,
            RunNotifier notifier) {
        EachTestNotifier eachNotifier = new EachTestNotifier(notifier, description);
        eachNotifier.fireTestStarted();
        try {
            statement.evaluate();   <-- test method execution is called from here
        } catch (AssumptionViolatedException e) {
            eachNotifier.addFailedAssumption(e);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            eachNotifier.addFailure(e);
        } finally {
            eachNotifier.fireTestFinished();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes - this is the correct answer. JUNIT is wrapping the test method with the try catch block so the exception is never treated as an UncaughtException (which is not the case when run via the main() method).  Kind of obvious now. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Obviously, the `setUncaughtExceptionHandler` sets handler for uncaught exceptions. But JUnit catches all exceptions thrown from test methods.

Anyway, it is weird way to make a unit test. Unit test should test your code, not JVM specification.

I imagine a unit test like this:

```
public class MyUncaughtExceptionHandlerTest
{
  @Mock Thread thread;
  MyUncaughtExceptionHandler testObject = new MyUncaughtExceptionHandler();

  @Before
  public void setUp()
  {
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void handleNpeShouldDoOneThing()
  {
    testObject.handleException(thread, new NullPointerException());
    //verify(oneThing)
  }

  @Test
  public void handleOomShouldDoSomethingElse()
  {
    testObject.handleException(thread, new OutOfMemoryError());
    //verify(somethingElse)
  }
}
```

Comment: It is an odd test - the 'real' code I want to test makes use of the Thread UncaughtExceptionHandler. So because junit acts this way I can't test that code (with junit). The test above is just to show the issue, I'm not trying to test the JVM spec.

Comment: @Rob You should make a `MyUncaughtExceptionHandlerTest` to test `MyUncaughtExceptionHandler`, call `uncaughtException` from the test. And forget about testing `java.lang.Thread` class instances, create mocks for them.

Comment: Hmmm, technically the testMethod() should not throw NPE or any exception as it will get caught by MyUncaughtExceptionHandler.  Somehow JUNIT is disabling that behavior and the exception is thrown. Ultimately my question morphs into HOW and WHY does JUNIT disable the Thread UncaughtExceptionHandler.

Comment: @Rob I've updated my answer to include an example of a unit test. The class itself should not care how its methods are invoked - by JVM or directly from a test method. JUnit should handle all exceptions thrown by a test method, because all tests run in one thread. Running each test in a separate thread would be bad solution I imagine.

Comment: Thanks but that is not what I am after. I'm not trying to test the behavior of Thread UncaughtExceptionHandler. The 'real' code uses enhacement and registers a UncaughtExceptionHandler. The 'real' test doesn't work because somehow JUNIT is disabling the UncaughtExceptionHandler - I don't know how it is doing that yet.

Comment: @Rob the uncaught exception handler is not for uncaught exceptions *within a stack frame*, it's for uncaught exceptions in the entire thread. From `Thread` Javadoc: "Returns the handler invoked when this thread abruptly terminates due to an uncaught exception.". In this case, the `Thread` does not abruptly terminate because JUnit catches and handles all exceptions.

Comment: @Rob Eugeniy has shown you the code, JUnit just catches exceptions by try-catch statement, nothing esoteric. It is pretty clear. Uncaught exception is an exception not wrapped into any catch statement. You could test your 'real' code by using getUncaughtExceptionHandler() to verify if the code sets the handler.

Comment: @Rob if you want to test that your code *sets* the uncaught exception handler, perhaps you could execute that code, then inspect the handler returned by `Thread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler`. But beware, you may no longer consider that a unit test, since that method relies on global mutable state, and isn't completely isolated from your other tests.