# Java convert from one exception to another

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, exception

I have a common project with some shared code that is being used in another project. I'm trying to convert/map the exception from the common project `CommonException` to a new type of Exception let's call it `SuperAwesomeException`.

The aim is to have a generic way of handling all custom exceptions in the project.

I've attempted to do this using an `UncaughtExceptionHandler`. This seems to work when running the project but not from within JUnit, since that wraps each test in a try/catch block as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994335/java-thread-currentthread-setuncaughtexceptionhandler-not-working-with-junit).

```
public final class ExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {        
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {            
        if (exception instanceof CommonException) {
            throw new SuperAwesomeException(exception.getMessage());
        }
        if (exception instanceof SuperAwesomeException) {
            throw new CommonException(exception.getMessage());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("ERROR! caught some other exception I don't really care about");
            System.out.println("Not doing anything");    
        }
    }
}
```

Is there another way I can map from one Exception to another or can I somehow tell JUnit not to catch certain exceptions and check the Exception is mapped to the correct one?

*UPDATE* - How I initially tried to write the Test:

```
public class ClassThatThrowsException {
    ClassThatThrowsException() {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler());
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        throw new CommonException("Something boring blew up!");
    }
}

public class ClassThatThrowsExceptionTest {    
    @Test(expected=SuperAwesomeException.class)
    public void testAwesome() {
        ClassThatThrowsException c = new ClassThatThrowsException();
        c.doSomething();
    }
}
```

which throws:

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<SuperAwesomeException> but was<CommonException>
```

Comment: If you scroll down that answer you will find `Unit test should test your code, not JVM specification`.  Why do you need such specification in a unit test?  Unit tests are usually viewed as pass/fail sort of things.

Comment: You should rather keep the first `exception` as the `cause` of the new one. By just copying the message, you get rid of the stackTrace, discarding useful information.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am trying to test my code. I want to test that under certain conditions an Exception gets thrown. But I want to Map the common exception to a more specific one for that project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is: when you are using **JUnit**, the *framework* will catch your exception. Therefore the *uncaught* exception handler isn't called in the first place!

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994335/java-thread-currentthread-setuncaughtexceptionhandler-not-working-with-junit) for more details.

Thus, you have to do *two* things:

A) write tests that make sure that your exception handler implementation works as desired

```
@Test(expected=SuperAwesomeException.class)
public void testAwesome() {
   new ExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(null, new CommonException("whatever"));
}
```

B) thest the *plumbing* - you want to make sure that this specific uncaught handler gets actually set by your code:

```
@Test
public void testDefaultHandlerIsSet() {
   // creating a new instance should update the handler!
   new ClassThatThrowsException();
   Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler handler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
   assertThat(handler, not(nullValue()));
   assertThat(handler, instanceOf(ExceptionHandler.class));
}
```

Finally - please note: you should **not** just do `new XException(oldException.getMessage)`. Rather go for `new XException("some message, oldException)`.

In other words: you got a *cause* here; so you better use the incoming exception as *cause* within the new one you intend to throw. Otherwise you loose all stack trace information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question with how I was attempting to write the test which unfortunately fails since JUnit catches the first exception instead of letting it be converted by the `ExceptionHandler` Is there a way I can get my test to work without needing to change the expected to be `Exception` and catch all which feels a bit hacky.

Comment: I like your test and will add something similar to my testsuite. I'm just thinking about all the other tests which will throw the exception that JUnit is currently breaking.

Comment: I had a closer look at your example and figured your problem. I *think* am addressing all your issues; now lets hope you agree and upvote/accept ... as spent quite some time here ;-)